# getting error in pos_tag using nltk in python

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

i am trying to `import nltk library` but getting error while using `nltk.pos_tag`

```
nltk.pos_tag(y)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    nltk.pos_tag(y)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 99, in pos_tag
    tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 605, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))
   ImportError: No module named numpy.core.multiarray
```

Answer (score 0):

You need numpy module and it seems you don't have it installed. If you read the steps of how to [install](http://nltk.org/install.html) nltk you can see that you need numpy.